# Multiple Inheritance: What's a good example?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to find a good example for the use of multiple inheritance what cannot be done with normal interfaces.

I think it's pretty hard to find such an example which cannot be modeled in another way.

Edit: I mean, can someone name me a good real-world example of when you NEED to use multiple inheritance to implement this example as clean as possible. And it should not make use of multiple interfaces, just the way you can inherit multiple classes in C++.

Comment: You accepted
[Luchian Grigore's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9360014/2932052), but are you really satisfied? I think this is a very good question (+1), but maybe not for SO, because it may not have a real answer that may convince the critical programmer.

Comment: I'm not very satisfied. I had to argue with a critical programmer back in the day and he didn't like the argument. I've simply given it up to be honest :D

Comment: Then it's maybe better to unaccept the "answer" that is nothing more than a sparse decorated quote of a (poor) Wikipedia example. Maybe there will be someone with a real answer in the future - no, most probably not me :-)

Answer (score 10):

The following is a classic:

```
class Animal {
 public:
  virtual void eat();
};

class Mammal : public Animal {
 public:
  virtual void breathe();
};

class WingedAnimal : public Animal {
 public:
  virtual void flap();
};

// A bat is a winged mammal
class Bat : public Mammal, public WingedAnimal {
};
```

Source: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Comment: This is done with interfaces, I wan't something which makes use of FULL class inheritance as it is possible in C++.

Comment: @PhilippSpieß which are the interfaces?

Comment: @PhilippSpieß also, what is full class inheritance?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore in your example class is  interchargeable with interface it makes no difference

Comment: @PizzaPill how so? `Animal::eat()` has an implementation, therefore it's not an interface.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore where is that implementation? I can't see it

Comment: @PizzaPill a virtual method that isn't declared pure must have an implementation, otherwise it won't compile. Look it up. I assumed everyone know this (apparently not) so I left it out. In C++ the implementation usually goes in implementation file (it's not mandated though).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore my C++ is rusty as hell, but this question never was about C++ so it doesn't matter. Problem with your example is, that the "Problem" can be easily solved with interfaces and delegates. Java programmers do this every day.

Comment: @PizzaPill The link I provided was about C++. Also, how can you solve this with interfaces if you need an implementation for `Animal::eat()`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore why would somebody need an implementation for Animal::eat()?

Comment: @PizzaPill most probably because most animals eat the same way. Why else?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore and why should this not be solvable by composition/delegation?

Comment: Because a `WingedAnimal` is-a `Animal`. A `WingedAnimal` doesn't contain an `Animal`. This sort of relationship is represented by inheritance, not delegation or composition. I'm starting to think 125 rep is too low of a limit for the downvote privilege.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I think this is an implementation detail, but lets agree to disagree here. Maybe OP will choose an answer. On a sidenote: What made you think I downvoted? And did you redo me the "favor" with a downvote on a perfectly good answer? Crazy!

Comment: @PizzaPill I did not, but I'd hardly call your answer good, since you're not providing a real-world example, are you now?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Im sorry I did downvote, dont know how that happened, wasn't a concious decision!

Comment: @PizzaPill and it's not am implementation detail. You might argue that the method `eat` can be overriden. I say no. The algorithm for eating is the same, implementation details are abstract method. For example, `eat()` could call `getFood`, `digest`, etc. in a specific order, and those method are the ones that need to be overriden by derived classes.

Comment: @PizzaPill you should stop that before we both get banned. It's your right to downvote, and I accept downvotes when they are legitimate. We don't hold grudges here.

Comment: I think, `breathe` as the typical innovation of the Mammal class is not a good choice. Ok, that's Wikipedias fault, but why quote it?

Answer (score 4):

One example where multiple class inheritance makes sense is the Observer pattern. This pattern describes two actors, the observer and the observable, and the former wants to be notified when the latter changes its object state.

A simplified version for notifying clients can look like this in C#:

```cs
public abstract class Observable
{
    private readonly List<IObserver> _observers = new List<IObserver>();

    // Objects that want to be notified when something changes in
    // the observable can call this method
    public void Subscribe(IObserver observer)
    {
        _observers.Add(observer);
    }

    // Subclasses can call this method when something changes
    // to notify all observers
    protected void Notify()
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
            observer.Notify();
    }
}
```

This basically is the core logic you need to notify all the registered observers. You could make any class observable by deriving from this class, but as C# does only support single class inheritance, you are limited to not derive from another class. Something like this wouldn't work:

```cs
public class ImportantBaseClass { /* Members */ }

public class MyObservableSubclass : ImportantBaseClass, Observable { /* Members */ }
```

In these cases you often have to replicate the code that makes subclasses observable in all of them, basically violating the Don't Repeat Yourself and the Single Point of Truth principles (if you did MVVM in C#, think about it: how often did you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?). A solution with multiple class inheritance would be much cleaner in my opinion. In C++, the above example would compile just fine.

[Uncle Bob wrote an interesting article about this](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/01/08/InterfaceConsideredHarmful.html), that is where I got the example from. But this problem often applies to all interfaces that are *able (e.g. comparable, equatable, enumerable, etc.): a multiple class inheritance version is often cleaner in these cases, as stated by Bertrand Meyer in his book "Object-Oriented Software Construction".