# Php and multiple-inheritance

Tags: php, oop, multiple-inheritance

i have the following simplified code

```
class A{}
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
```

It is working perfectly and everything is ok, but i wanted to make sure that it's not bad practice so i googled "multiple inheritance in php" and was surprised that many posts  i read said that multiple inheritance in php is not supported and the alternative is traits.

So i doubted my definition of multiple inheritance and googled a good example about it and this [Multiple Inheritance: What's a good example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359948/multiple-inheritance-whats-a-good-example) came up, and it is in fact exactly as what i was doing but in a different context.

can someone shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Because it's __not__ multiple inheritance. It's just two-levels inheritance, but each class has only one parent

Comment: You just created a grandchild class, not multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ChristopherLamm can you please take a look at the answer of the question i linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using multiple inheritance, you pasted an example of polymorphism.

Multiple inheritace = multiple parents

```
class Animal {}   
class Mammal extends Animal {} //single inheritance
class WingedAnimal extends Animal {} //single inheritance
class Bat extends Mammal extends WingedAnimal {} //multiple inheritance, not supported by PHP.
```

Comment: then what's with the answer of the question i linked. @Naktibalda

Comment: so the answer in the link is not correct right?  @Naktibalda

Comment: Answer in the link is correct. But there is no multiple inheritance in your code.