# When does multiple inheritance come in handy?

Tags: inheritance, architecture, multiple-inheritance

Can you provide some real-world examples when problem can be more easily addressed using multiple inheritance rather than using composition or other alternatives?

When should one use multiple inheritance?

Why do some languages support multiple inheritance (C++, Python) and others don't (Java, Ruby)? I mean - based on what factors do creators of programming languages decide to include support for MI or not.

Answer (score 12):

Multiple inheritance is mostly used for integration purposes, i.e. when you need an object that implements all the required functionality of the classes it derives from. Whether this amounts to a "better" solution than possible alternatives, is a matter of debate or taste, so you're probably lucky that this question wasn't closed as primarily opinion-based.

With regard to examples,

- this article on [using Python's super() for multiple
  inheritance](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
  shows an example of implementation sharing. You can't have this with
  interfaces or composition,
- a similar example is explained on the [Wikipedia page on multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) for deriving `Button` from `Rectangle` and `Clickable` (it also has a long list of languages supporting MI),
- an answer to a previous question [for good MI examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31178549/3098550) points to `Observable` and the like, which at least Bertrand Meyer claims to be cleaner implemented with MI than without (hence you're also lucky that this question didn't get closed as a duplicate).

From personal experience, multiple inheritance can be quite helpful, but it can also be a big problem easily. The Wikipedia page discusses the *Diamond* problem to some extent: it boils down to the question what should happen if two or more base classes provide an implementation of some method. Languages need to define / implement a way to deal with this, typically by defining some method resolution order (e.g. [Python's mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)).

The conflict potential increases, of course, with the number of base classes and the number of methods. I had a case once where the framework (implemented in Python) we were using employed multiple inheritance of a handful of base classes for some class we had derived from. We could then happily override an inherited method without being aware of it.

Multiple inheritance, while sometimes useful, can be seen as a violation of the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle): by definition, a class deriving from multiple base classes will behave like either class. It's hence also quite likely that from a data modelling perspective, the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is also violated.

So, I believe that creators of programming languages might recognize that multiple inheritance is seen as not free of conceptual issues and might require substantial implementation effort while providing only limited added value over other solutions -- but that's just my personal guess.

Comment: Raymond Hettinger's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) on super() considered super is pretty super!

Comment: Upvote for well thought out answer, but yes the OP should be closed as belongs elsewhere, too vague and very opinion based - but it wont let me flag because of the bounty ;)

Comment: @DanielB It looks like I've hacked the system. I'm new to SO. I'm not yet used to the rules and this topic seems interesting for me.

Comment: @Luke - it is an interesting topic, but rather vague and by definition opinionated, and dont comply with SO (or most stackoverflow websites) so far as i understand (though kudos for schaueho for giving it a decent answer). I havent used them much, but I know these questions work well in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/, plenty of rooms there you could talk about concepts how ever vague

Answer (score 8):

Answering your last question first: The reason that some languages don't support multiple inheritance is because it is rarely necessary and tends to make the code much more complicated compared to composition or multiple interface inheritance.

This relates to your first two questions in that it is difficult to find a real-world example (at least, a simple one) where M.I. could solve a problem easily. Clearly, the creators of languages where M.I. is not supported think you should never use it. I would guess that the reason that some languages *do* support it is because the creators saw no reason not to.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx) is a link to a frequently asked question on MSDN that explains why C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Moreover, M.I is really hard to implement for a language.
However the first reason is described by Matt.

Comment: @AntoineFoucault I guess you mean hard for the creators of a language. And why is that? Any evidence or arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Real-world example: I've encountered one situation when multiple inheritance really made a lot of sense, it is for the C++ implementation of the [Vector Animation Complex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xk1_CugdytI).

It is a topological data-structure immersed in space-time. Conceptually, it is similar to a graph, except that instead of "nodes+edges", it has:

- vertices+edges+faces in the spatial domain
- keys+inbetweens in the temporal domain

Because the data-structure is a cross product between space and time, you have in total 6 classes:

1. KeyVertex
2. KeyEdge
3. KeyFace
4. InbetweenVertex
5. InbetweenEdge
6. InbetweenFace

The way I implemented it is via multiple inheritance. There is a virtual base class:

```cpp
class Cell;
```

Then, there are three virtual classes to implement the "spatial behaviour" of these cells, and two virtual classes to implement the "temporal behaviour":

```cpp
class VertexCell:    virtual public Cell; 
class EdgeCell:      virtual public Cell; 
class FaceCell:      virtual public Cell; 

class KeyCell:       virtual public Cell; 
class InbetweenCell: virtual public Cell;
```

Finally, the actual non-virtual classes are defined with multiple inheritance:

```cpp
class KeyVertex:       public KeyCell,       public VertexCell; 
class KeyEdge:         public KeyCell,       public EdgeCell; 
class KeyFace:         public KeyCell,       public FaceCell; 
class InbetweenVertex: public InbetweenCell, public VertexCell; 
class InbetweenEdge:   public InbetweenCell, public EdgeCell; 
class InbetweenFace:   public InbetweenCell, public FaceCell;
```

In addition to make sense mathematically and conceptually, it had two practical advantages:

1. Maximizing shared code. Code sharing can also be achieved with composition, but it would have required more boilerplate.
2. Casting to base classes. Sometimes, I need a big container to manage all cells, so it's great that they all inherit `Cell`, as I can have a `vector<Cell*>` and directly call the virtual methods shared by all cells (for instance `draw()`). Sometimes, I need a `vector<VertexCell*>`. Sometimes, I need a `vector<KeyCell*>`.

In fact, I have even written convenient containers so that I can do things like:

```cpp
CellPtrSet cells = getCells();
KeyCellPtrSet keyCells = cells; // Cast and copy those which are actually key cells
```

In a nutshell, multiple inheritance made possible to have a very nice and clean API to write algorithms working with these cells. And it nicely reflects the underlying mathematical structure.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of modern languages supporting some kind of multiple inheritance are Java and Scala. Java has default interface methods since Java8 and Scala has traits that can contain methods and data.

Now, usage examples:

- Define useful methods that invoke abstract methods. For example, Collection.removeIf in Java - it removes elements based on provided predicate. Thus, every class implementing Collection will have removeIf method.
- Split class with lots and lots public methods into smaller units of code. There are cases when aggregation does not work and we really need half-a-hundred public methods in single class. Multiple inheritance allows better management of such code.
- DSLs. You can add DSL to your code by inheriting from class that implements that DSL.
- Add some behavior to your objects. In C++ you can use  multiple inheritance to add reference counter to every object for memory management.

In short, multiple inheritance of code is very useful. Multiple inheritance of data is more questionable and should be used with caution.

Comment: I don't think Java default method is a sort of multiple inheritance. compiler will complain in such a case, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

MI or multiple inheritance is a very common topic of debate, be careful what you ask for...
I will try and give you a short answer, as my professor once said 'inheritance simulate real life, when your object in real life is inheriting features so does your objects'.
at the end of the day you must think about the programmer that is using your class, does he need to know your composite objects? or maybe it's better he will just call functions of a 'closed box'. the best example is washing machine, it has buttons and many washing features but you don't really care what is going on inside, so does your class, if i use it i don't need to know the objects that makes it just the functions. it would be even better if i know only the interface.

You should use multiple inheritance when you want to avoid copying code and when a change will have to be fixed in several places.

About your last question, the languages are designed differently due to many many reasons and it will be a long answer if we start comparing them.